# Translation from Camera Coordinates System to Robotic-Arm Coordinates System

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates, robotics, coordinate-transformation

I am new in robotics and I am working on a project where I need to pass the coordinates from the camera to the robot.

So the **robot** is just an arm, it is then stable in a **fixed position**. I do not even need the 'z' axis because the board or the table where everything is going on have always the same 'z' coordinates.

The **webcam** as well is always in a **fixed position**, it is not part of the robot and it does not move.

The **problem** I am having is in the conversion from 2D camera coordinates to a 3D robotic arm coordinates (2D is enough because as stated before the 'z' axis is not needed as is always in a fixed position).

I'd like to know from you guys, which one is the **best approach** to face this kind of problems so I can start to research.

I've found lot of information on the web but I am getting a lot of confusion, I would really appreciate if someone could address me to the right way.

I don't know if this information are useful but I am using OpenCV3.2 with Python

Thank you in advance

Comment: OpenCV is only the tool to work with the camera and, eventually, retrieve coordinates of points in the world in the camera coordinates system. I have to ask: would you retrieve the position of the robot (in a plane) from the image taken from the camera? If you know both camera coordinates and arm coordinates in a world reference system, is just a rototranslation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @marcoresk. Yes i can retrieve the position of the arm. Which will be the best approach to apply this rototlansation?

Comment: 2D coordinates are 3D with z = 0. Then you can be interested in a [forward 3d transfomation matrix](https://studywolf.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/robot-control-forward-transformation-matrices/)

Answer (score 0):

Define your 2D coordinate on the board, create a mapping from the image coordinate (2D) to the 2D board, and also create a mapping from the board to robot coordinate (3D). Usually, robot controller has a function to define your own coordinate (the board).